# Caching not working - Ehcache + Spring annotation

Tags: spring, jdbc, ehcache, spring-annotations

I am new to Ehcache. I tried an example with Spring and Ehcache. 
Caching doesn't seem to work. When I try to debug, service layer returns the object but it is not cached. The keys in the cache is null.

Below is my code:

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml, /WEB-INF/cache-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Cache-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
     http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

    <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />
    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:config-location="/WEB-INF/ehcache-config.xml" p:shared="true"/>
</beans>
```

ehcache-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100"
        overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="userCache" maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false" />   
</ehcache>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test.htm")    
    public void getUsers() {


        loginService.getUser();

        Cache userCache = this.cacheManager.getCache("userCache");

        List<String> userCacheKey = userCache.getKeys();        

    }
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(cacheName="userCache")   
public User getUser() { 

    String SQLUSERByName = "SELECT * FROM User where user_id=1000";
    User user= getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(SQLUSERByName, new UserMapper());   
    return user;

}
```

I am using Spring 3.1 version.

Comment: Please add the spring version you're using.

Comment: I resolved the issue. Above code works. (Problem was in different part of code)

Comment: @Leks Hi, I am also facing same problem could you please help me what should I check in my code?

Comment: @Balasaheb can you please tell the exact problem?

Comment: @Leks - I'm having the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924873/cachable-annotation-does-not-work

Do you have any idea what can I do?

Also, it is usually a good practice to give an answer instead of changing the code. This way you can help others find the answer. Edited code does not reflect the changes from the original problematic code to the new, fixed, code.

Thanks!