# @Cachable annotation does not work

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-annotations

We're using ehcache for caching purposes in our project.

```
import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable;
// Other imports

@Component
public class Authenticator{
    @Cacheable(cacheName = "rest_client_authorized")
    public boolean isUserAuthorized(final String user, final String sessionId) {
        // Method code
    }
}
```

When entering the method there is no cache interceptor. The things we checked so far:

1. We don't call this method from inside the class, but from the outside. So the problem is not inner calls that causes to bypass the proxy.
2. We've added an interface for this class, and we changed the injections where this class is called to use the interface representation instead of the concrete class.

We have defined the cache manager in our application context this way:

```
   <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />         
   <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
       <!-- use a share singleton CacheManager -->
       <property name="shared" value="true" />
   </bean>
```

The cache is defined like this:

```
        <cache name="rest_client_authorized"
            eternal="false"
            maxElementsInMemory="50"
            overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

When we test the cache manager using Jconsole we can see that the cache *rest_auth_disabled* exists and empty.

Any ideas as to why this does not work will be most appreciated. Thanks!

**Updates (aggregation from comments below)**:

==========================================**

That's a legacy code that worked fine with the class and definitions I've provided. The method I talk about here is new, but the rest of the class did work in past. So we're struggling to understand what has changed. We also tried already to replace the annotation to spring Cacheable, but still nothing :/
Maybe that depends on the code that calls this new method, which is from a different spring bean than what we used for the other methods. But I still can't find the issue.

Also tried to return Boolean instead of boolean following an answer below and it didn't work.
We have a new lead which is probably related to the way we inject the bean (using @Autowire). Will update if that's indeed the case.

Comment: What persistence provider do you use? When using hibernate, see [HH-5303](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5303)

Comment: Well, we use Hibernate indeed. But we already used @Cacheable in this project and it worked. The cache is cached in-memory and not in the DB .
Also, please note that this is not a JPA annotation, so I'm not sure that's the case. What do you think?

Comment: You are right, I did not read the actual import statement and assumed it was the JPA annotation you were talking about. What application server do you use?

Comment: Hm, I do not know that server. Have you enabled caching in the persistence.xml? "<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />". I do not know if it is necessary for your server, though.

Comment: tc-server is the spring version of tomcat7, they are basically identical.
Do I need to enable this hibernate property even if I'm not using the DB as cache?

Comment: Hm. You are right, what I said makes no sense. Maybe caching does not work with boolean return types? All examples I saw use objects, no primitives.

Comment: Sounds very un-likely. Methods returning primitive types can also be very time/resource-consuming

Comment: Any more ideas anyone?

Comment: I think it's lke @SvenPlath said (didn't read these comments). Spring ehcache requires that your parameters/return object has an `equals()` and `hashCode()` method and primitives lacks both.
Consider using wrapper classes and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem might have to do with the order Springs loads the beans. Try removing the @Autowire annotation from the Authenticator declartion, and do the autowiring manually. Something like:

```
/**
 * Class that uses Authenticator
 */

 public class X {

    // Don't use @autowire here
    public Authenticator athenticator;

    public void doSomething() {
         manuallyAutowire();
    }

    public void manuallyAutowire() {
         if(authenticator == null) {
    authenticator = ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext().
                            getBean(authenticator.class);
    }
}
```

Where

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext appContext) 
                                          throws BeansException {
         ctx = appContext;

    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone elaborate on WHY this is the case?  Having annotations just not work is extremely poor.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the parameter **cacheName** in @Cacheable should be the same with the value of the **name** attribute of **<cache>** declaration in your application-context

Comment: You're right, and it is the same. I just copied a different xml entry by mistake. I fixed it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up things here - You have used `com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable`, if you want Springs caching support it should actually be `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`. Then the caching interceptors should work cleanly.

Comment: The problem is - That's a legacy code the worked fine with the code and definitions I've provided. The method I talk about here is new, but the rest of the class did work in past. So we're struggling to understand what has changed.

We also tried already to replace the annotation to spring Cacheable, but still nothing :/

Comment: Oh, okay, I am not familiar with ehcache Spring annotation support, but if you are using Spring's @Cacheable(org.spring..) then you will also have to change `<ehcache:annotation-driven/>` to `<cache:annotation-driven/>`, cache prefix in namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache`, this should create the proxies for you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Spring Ehcache annotations recommends that both parameter as return object should have an `equals()` and `hashCode()` method which primitive types lack.

I'm not sure if this framework is converting primitives to their wrapper variant (for example `Integer` or `Boolean`). Try returning the wrapper variant `Boolean` in stead of a primitive type and see if it works.

Another thing I'm not sure about is how (and if) it handles `final` parameters. If my first idea doesn't work, try removing the `final` keyword if possible and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, those are great inputs! I'll check it out and report the results. Thanks!